# Join Two Tables without foreign keys in Spring Boot with similar Ids

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here I have two tables; both have IDs as primary keys. I want to know how to join these tables without foreign keys, based on their IDs. What should be the service implementation and what should be in the repository? How to write `@Query` with `JOINS`?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "procedures")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Procedure implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ProcedureId")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ProcedureName")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ProcedureCode")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "ProcedureDesc")
    private String desc;
//  getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliniciandescriptor")
public class CPTClinicianDescriptor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ConceptId")
    private int conceptId;

    @Column(name = "CPTCode")
    private String cptCode;

    @Column(name = "ClinicianDescriptorId")
    private int clinicianDescriptorId;


    @Column(name = "ClinicianDescriptor")
    private String clinicianDescriptor;
//  getters and setters
}
```

Comment: why don't you want to use foreign keys? Also: `ProcedureCode` and `CPTCode` look like natural primary keys to me, so you should think about not using the surrogate `id` columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering it as One-to-One relation, you can use something like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "procedures")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Procedure implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ProcedureId")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ProcedureName")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ProcedureCode")
    private String code;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private CPTClinicianDescriptor  descriptor;

    @Column(name = "ProcedureDesc")
    private String desc;
//  getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Hi Im getting the result thank you, I can add one more ```@JoinColumn``` if I want to get from other table also right?

Comment: @RaviChandraT Yes, you can add multiple.

Comment: Thank you, and I have a doubt if i have a mapping table(CPTProcedures) which has a foreign key of Procedures and ClinicianDesc as mentioned above without adding ```@JoinColumn``` in Procedures can i get the list of Procedures with ClinicianDesc and I want to write list for Procedure Controller not for that CPTProcedures

Answer (score 4):

You can use the JOIN on syntax like in SQL

For example

```
select p from Procedure p join CPTClinicianDescriptor c on c.id = p.id;
```

Read more about that topic here:
https://72.services/how-to-join-two-entities-without-mapped-relationship/

Comment: when I write this as We are printing ```p``` it printing only Procedure's list it is not combined with CPTClinicianDescriptor